# Controlling Stepper Motor Responding Strangely

Tags: raspbian, gpio, hardware, pwm, pi-2

I'm attempting to simply move a small stepper motor over GPIO using a Sparkfun Easy Driver. This [Stepper](http://www.aliexpress.com/store/product/2PCS-Hollow-Shaft-Hybrid-Stepping-Motor-4-Phase-5-Wire-Square-1-8-Degrees-39MM-Stepper/337908_32285146289.html) motor is the one I'm attempting to use. I'm using similar code and configuration to that shown in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bRgHP8C5b9k) video. The motor does move in response, but only oscillates in place. Is this because I have a four phase motor hooked up like a bipolar, is it because the raspberry pi isn't putting out enough amperage, or is this a danger of using a pwm input.[image: photo of wiring]

Thanks

Comment: Do you have any load on the stepper motor or are you allowing it to move freely? while testing I would run the motor without any weight.

Comment: There's no load. There's a tiny spec of post-it attached to it to see if it's going around but that's it.

Comment: Just a guess as I've run into that before. Have you tried adjusting the delays? Also the class `Adafruit_StepperMotor` in this [adafruit samble](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-Motor-HAT-Python-Library/blob/master/Adafruit_MotorHAT/Adafruit_MotorHAT.py) might be useful.

Comment: I've played with the delays, but that just shifts the rate of oscillation. I have an arduino that I'm going to use to see if the motor is broken and a raspberry pi motor shield that I'm going to experiment with to try and pinpoint the problem.

Comment: Why not post a photo of your wiring?  Oscillation usually indicates the phases are incorrectly wired.

Comment: I thought the same thing and tried out some different wirings. I'm following the recommended wiring from the product link that I posted.

Comment: Unfortunately there are 24 wiring possibilities.  I don't think it can do any harm if you cycle through them.  When I use the Pi to drive a stepper (via a ULN2003A) I have a program which tries each possibility in turn and I make a note of which works.

Comment: Well, I've now gone through all 24 wiring possibilities with no luck and even switched to an Arduino to see if that would help. Faulty motor?